# SQL Server getdate() returning weird results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a bit of a small issue:

```
GO
declare @datetime varchar(25);
select @datetime = getdate();
select cast(convert(varchar(8), @datetime, 112) as varchar)
GO
```

That is returning this: Apr  1 2

however this:

```
GO
declare @datetime varchar(25);
select @datetime = getdate();
select cast(convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 112) as varchar)
GO
```

returns : 20140401

(Which is what we want), so why is the declare messing it up? and how do I get the results like the second return? (This is within a Trigger btw, but this is the messed up part)

Comment: As an aside, why would you ever cast as varchar without declaring a length? [Please don't do that - here's why](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the datatype of @datetime to DATETIME

```
declare @datetime DATETIME;
select @datetime = getdate();
select cast(convert(varchar(8), @datetime, 112) as varchar)
```

There is an implicit conversion from `varchar to datatime` which is happening at `select @datetime = getdate();` and which results in the wierd behavior

Answer (score 5):

Try the first one with this changes:

```
GO
declare @datetime DATETIME;
select @datetime = getdate();
select cast(convert(varchar(8), @datetime, 112) as varchar)
GO
```

The problem results from the varchar data type and the incorrect cast you use by selecting the  result from `GETDATE()` into the varchar.

Comment: You beat me to it! +1

Comment: Sometimes you know the solution but you cant see it :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case:

```
declare @datetime varchar(25);
select @datetime = getdate();
select cast(convert(varchar(8), @datetime, 112) as varchar)
```

`@datetime` is a `VARCHAR` value which contains `"Apr 1 2014 ...."`.  When you `CONVERT` it to a `VARCHAR(8)` all that happens is it is truncated to 8 characters - the "style" parameter is ignored.

If you declare `@datetime` ad a `DATETIME` then it will stay a `DATETIME` value and `CONVERT` will convert it to a string using the format you specify.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit conversion on this line:

```
select @datetime = getdate();
```

Why don't you declare @datetime as datetime type?

Answer (score 0):

```
GO
declare @datetime SMALLDATETIME;
select @datetime = getdate();
select cast(convert(varchar(8), @datetime, 112) as varchar)
GO
```

Why store it as a varchar? Keep it as a date time until you have to cast it out.

The above code returns correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned it to varchar variable. You can also use it directly

```
select cast(convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 112) as varchar)
```